# Using Wikipedia API for autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, jsonp, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I want to use the Wikipedia API to select a famous person's name from the **People** category from my Javascript application. Basically, I would like to send the name or partial name and get results that contains the Wikipedia URL, title, an excerpt of the content and if possible the main picture.

I have been trying two ways, but I cannot make it work as I want.

First I have tried with [search](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search), but I cannot find the way of make it return the url. Would `sectiontitle` be good as unique identifier? Can `snippet` be plain text somehow? Cannot find how to filter by category.

Second, I have tried with [opensearch](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch), but the JSON response does not contain images, while the XML response does:

JSON: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=mariano&namespace=0&format=json

XML: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=mariano&namespace=0&format=xml

It is not possible to filter by category. Also, some results include a link to the disambiguation page, when I would prefer to get the list of possible matches rather than such link.

How could I search by title and get full title, url, small description and a picture link?

Answer (score 3):

Opensearch is for input field autocompletion; it's based on an [external spec](http://www.opensearch.org/) and not very flexible. You should use the search API as a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) for some other API such as info which can return more details ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=meaning&prop=info&inprop=url)).